# pass an array to a function

Tags: processing

In processing, lets say I have an array:

```java
int[] rgb = {floor(random(0,255)), floor(random(0,255)), floor(random(0,255)};
```

So this will create an array with [0], [1], and [2] being corresponding red, green. and blue values.

Now let's say that I want to pass the `fill()` function, which needs 3 integers--red, green, and blue. I could just put `fill(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);`, but that does not seem like the most efficient way of doing this. What I want is to be able to pass something like this to `fill()`:

`fill(rgb[0,1,2]);` which will do the same thing as `fill(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);`, but will be much less writing. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Languages have defined syntax so that they can be compiled into something executable by a computer. That said, you usually can define your method signature to take what ever you want. What language are you working with?

Comment: processing (mentioned in post)

Comment: sorry didn't even know that was a thing

Comment: processing.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used processing, but you can probably [overload](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Function_overloading) the `fill` method to take an array.

```
void fill(int[] rgb)
{
    fill(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
};
```

Which you could then easily call like...

```
int[] rgb = {floor(random(0,255)), floor(random(0,255)), floor(random(0,255)};
fill(rgb);
```

There is a section in [this article](https://processing.org/tutorials/anatomy/) called "Too Many Parameters", I think it will help more.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing your fields in an array, store them in an object.

Processing has a `color` datatype that you could use. The `color()` function takes three arguments, and you can then pass the single `color` value to the `fill()` function. Like this:

```java
color myColor = color(random(256), random(256), random(256));
fill(myColor);
```

You could also [create your own class](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/creating-classes) and use that instead.